# wget download in an external HD runs but does not create folders

Tags: wget

I am using wget to download files in an external HD. While appartently the code runs without problems, no files or folder are created in the target directory.

How can it be solved?

My code is:

```
wget --http-user=xxxxxx --http-password=xxxxx --load-cookies mycookies.txt --save-cookies mycookies.txt --keep-session-cookies -r --reject "index.html*" -np -e robots=off https://n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org/SMAP/SPL4SMGP.003/ --directory-prefix=G/wget/
```

Comment: This question is about the **usage** of a program and should thus be asked on superuser.com, not on stackoverflow.com. Also, you should absolutely anonymize usernames and passwords before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks.

However I solved the problem.The right command is

```
wget --http-user=user --http-password=password --load-cookies mycookies.txt --save-cookies mycookies.txt --keep-session-cookies -r --reject "index.html*" -np -e robots=off https://n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org/SMAP/SPL4SMGP.003/ -P G:/wget/
```